# Override a plugin class

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to override a plugin class with my own.

The plugin class is

```
  function yith_woocompare_constructor() {
           // stuff here

 }
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'yith_woocompare_constructor' );
```

So in my functions.php I tried to do like that

```
     remove_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'yith_woocompare_constructor', 0 );   
// now add your own filter
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'new_yith_woocompare_constructor', 0 );

   function new_yith_woocompare_constructor()
    { 
      // my stuff here 
     }
```

But It doesn't seem to be working, what Am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What does return value of remove_action ?

Comment: remove_action return true or false, what is the value ?

Comment: Hm, how should I check this ?

default probably, I haven't set up anything more, than those lines above

Comment: echo ? $_SESSION["friend"] = remove_action(...); ? Or see here : http://fuelyourcoding.com/simple-debugging-with-wordpress/

Comment: Hmm, after adding this    `echo $_SESSION["friend"] = remove_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'woocommerce_ssys_recently_viewed_init');`  It returns `1` but I don't know if it's correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

The default priority is 10 but you're using 0. In your version you're not actually removing the action.

Also depending on the point your plugin loads it won't work anyway.

Try this instead.

```
function wpse_plugins_loaded() {
    remove_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'yith_woocompare_constructor' );   
    add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'new_yith_woocompare_constructor' );
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'wpse_plugins_loaded', 5 );

function new_yith_woocompare_constructor() {

}
```

In this example we're waiting for all the plugins to load to remove the 'yith_woocompare_constructor' action. We're calling the remove_action on plugins loaded with a priority of 5. This means the action will be removed before it is run (on 10) then replacing it with the custom function.

Comment: It hasn't changed anything ;( 
I checked the value like that  `if (! remove_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'yith_woocompare_constructor') ) {
    echo 'FAILED to remove action<br/>';`
And the failure is being displayed

Comment: Child theme  functions.php  

I just dont know, I did override other plugins without any problems, but I just cant this one

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by mu-plugins.

create directory name

**mu-plugins** parallel to **plugins**  folder and in folder create file
**wp-plugin-extended.php** , if your pluing name is **wp-plugin.php** 
 and do the code

```
function yith_woocompare_constructor() {
           // stuff here

 }
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'yith_woocompare_constructor' );
```